# How do I connect to Oracle Server without installing Oracle Client on client machines?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

I am using Microsoft VB.Net to create a Windows application, and would like some suggestions on how to connect to an Oracle database.

Answer (score 1):

use jdbc [JDBC Driver Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html) or maybe
[ODAC for Windows](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/downloads/index.html)

Comment: I don't think you can use a JDBC driver from within a VB.Net application (which is what Kalyan is using)